# JSON response on mobile - How to updating the DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use these tools: bootstrap, jquery, last versions.

I have a simple modal with a form inside. I POST the form through AJAX call and get the json response from server. With the response I update the modal-body (simple showing the feedback of submission).

To do that, I use $(".modal-body").html(data.feedback);

Desktop works fine! ... but in mobile (tablet and smartphone) seems that I can't manipulate the DOM. I can't see the feedback message. 
The ajax call still works, all the form data is stored in database but jquery doesn't update the content in the class modal-body.

Anyone can put me in the right way?
Thanks

Comment: how do you generate your modal? jquery-ui?

Comment: Secondly, is your mobile 'site' on jQuery Mobile or just the same?

Comment: I use Bootstrap modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I don't use jquery mobile. Just the last version of jquery.